# How do I remove stuck notification?

Tags: notifications, nexus-7, notification-bar

I have a notification from the TED app that refuses to go away. I tried clearing app data and rebooting and it didn't go away. I tried uninstalling and rebooting and it didn't go away. Is factory reset my only other option now?

I'm using a nexus-7 running stock build JOP40D (4.2.1). The device is not rooted.

Comment: What is the notification? Can you post a screenshot?

Comment: Please also include the Android version running on your device, might prove helpful.

Comment: Also what device you are using would be nice.

Answer (score 2):

Go into the app info by going into settings applications and finding your Ted app or dragging it from the launcher to the app info button. Disable and re-enable notifications with the "show notification" button.